# How to bind dynamic data from the database to the Datagrid ?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, jsp

I am reading dynamic data from the MySQL using JSP and it's forwarding the details in the form of XML to the Flex. I would like to bind this XML data to the datagrid. Am able to bind the data if the datagrid has only one column but don't know how to bind data which contains 2-3 columns.

My JSP will forward the details in the following format :

```
<people>
 <person>
  <X></X>
  <Y></Y>
  <Z></Z>
 </person>
 <person>
  <X></X>
  <Y></Y>
  <Z></Z>
 </person>
</people>
```

Using HTTP Service am able to display this as an Alert message in the Flex but don't know how to bind this to a datagrid. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of examples for this on the web. You want something like:

`yourDataGrid.dataprovider = yourHTTPRequest.lastresult.people.person`

or

`yourDataGrid.dataprovider = yourHTTPRequest.lastresult.people`

forgive me I have never learnt this. I just try both and see what works. =)

That (or something along those lines) will populate your datagrid, but make sure the `dataField` attributes for each column matches the same of the XML field you want to store in there.

Comment: Hurray, it's working now. I made a mistake in the dataField names. However, can you please let me know if I save the XML file into Array Collection and give the dataprovider as the array collection. I tried with single field and it's working fine. I don't know, how to save multi field values in an ArrayCollection and give it as the dataprovider to the Datagrid.

Comment: Well. There's the `XMLListCollection` class. I think that could be what you need. I don't know how to convert a XML file into an `ArrayCollection`.